# Resource manager

Tags: c++

I'm working on a resource manager for a game engine.

It should be able to manage images, textures, meshes, but this is not the problem. When a resource is loaded, the manager will check if this resource is not already in a "cache" (a ptr is stored in a typical data structure).

I'm wondering what kind of resource I should send back to the user if its already loaded.
I was thinking about a const ptr

```
template <typename T>
const T* getResource(string resourceName)
```

But it avoid the possibility to modify the resource itself. 
If I send a non-const ptr, the user will be able to modify the resource which will provoke multiple repercussions.

What about a shared_ptr?

Any advices?

Comment: If the resource is loaded, why not send back a handle (pointer) to it, and if it's not loaded, then load it and return the handle to the then-loaded resource afterwards?

Comment: Does the resource user __need__ to modify the resource?

Comment: The question here was more specifically about the kind of handle I should send back (const, shared) or simply a raw ptr. The user doesn't need to modify the resource, but it would be great to give him this possibility

Comment: The new smart pointers in C++11 can be seen as ownership of a resource. With `std::unique_ptr` there can be only one owner at a time, with `std::shared_ptr` there can be multiple owners. In the case of a resource manager, using `std::shared_ptr` kind of makes sense. Though you might want to look into [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) as well.

Comment: And having a `std::shared_ptr` isn't exclusive, you can as well have a `std::shared_ptr` to constant data.

Comment: I think std::weak_ptr is the pointer of this case. The resource is managed internally by the manager, so reference counting makes no sense on the user side, I think.

Answer (score 2):

A major problem with enabling the user of the resource manager to edit/modify the data, is that the data may need to be enlarged or made smaller.

Instead of having a single `getResource` that returns a non-const pointer (shared or not), why not have a `getResourse` function which returns a pointer to constant data, and then if the user need to modify that the user have to copy it to some private memory, and modify that, then have a `setResource` function to set the new resource data, with correct size.

Comment: That seems to be a great idea. Thanks :)

Comment: For good game engine I think it's better to avoid copying data in RAM as possible. If You want modify data use resource lock instead, it's much cheaper, than whole data copy * n_times. For small data (short strings...) Your answer is acceptable of course, but not for texture data. Never copy that. It must be loaded to RAM just once, then loaded to VRAM, then used by GPU. GPU may copy some parts of texture in VRAM which should be fast.

Answer (score 2):

In my ResourceManager I store a map which takes a `std::string` as the lookup and stores a `std::unique_ptr<Resource>`.

```
std::map map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Resource>>;
```

Then I have a get function that looks something like this

```
const Resource& get(const std::string& name)
{
    //search map for name, if it exists return it, else construct then return it
    auto found = map.find(name);
    if(found != map.end())
    {
        return *found->second;
    }

    // otherwise construct then return from map
}
```

I also have an overloaded function that can take extra params(such as texture rectangles for sprite sheets) etc, and another function that just returns `Resource&` as opposed to the const one. The const ref one can be used therefore to prevent changing the object elsewhere.

This means that the ResourceManager takes care of the ownership of the resources and if we ensure the resource manager is not destructed before the end of the game application that the resource scope will always be valid. This way of handling resources also prevents having to check if the resources are null before we use them elsewhere in the application(assuming you do some error checking on construction of the resource and the resource is initially in a valid state)

A use case is then as follows

```
ResourceManager<Texture> texture_manager_;

// If texture.png exists already then we just get a ref
// otherwise it gets constructed, checked for validity, stored in the map
// and then returned as a ref. That way we know the object is in a valid state
Texture tex = texture_manager.get("texture.png");
```

The final benefit is that this ResourceManager makes use of RAII and everything in the map will be destructed correctly when the ResourceManager goes out of scope(which presumably will be at a controlled point i.e. the end of the application)